# Encoding issue when retrieving text from QTableWidgetItem

Tags: encoding, utf-8, python-3.4, pyqt5

I'm working on a GUI using PyQt5 and a `QTableWidget` containing CheckBoxes items. I populate the table with data from json file and the user can check/uncheck items.

When I want to retrieve data from my `QTableWidget` items, I get unexpected error due to some characters : `\x19`. The character in question is `’` which is well displayed elsewhere.

I don't understand the issue as my input json data is utf-8, I use python3 and when I check my data, I see no encoding issue. This error occurs only when calling `text()` method on `QTableWidgetItem`. 
As I don't see any other way to retrieve data from my items, I'm quite stuck on it.

```
with open(filepath) as file:
    self.data = json.load(file)
    for key, value in self.data.items():
        print(key, self.data[key])
        keyword_box = QTableWidgetItem(key)
```

I get no error if I use `key` to compare with other string for example but when I want to retrieve data (no editing was performed by the user, strings didn't change)

```
items = self.table.selectedItems()
    for item in items:
        print(item.text())
```

I get unknown character in my console and if I try to use the value, I get a `\x19` character which fails when I use it to compare with keys in my dictionary.

Could this come from a bug in `QTableWidgetItem` `text()` method ?

Comment: What is the output of `print(repr(key))` and `print(repr(item.text()))`?

Comment: `print(repr(key))` gives `'détruits . d’ autres bâtiment'`. 

`print(repr(item.text())` gives `'détruits . d\x19 autres bâtiment'`.

Comment: I get this only with this string. With other keys, `repr(key)` and `repr(item.text())` return the same value.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this when using PyQt-5.5.0, PyQt-5.4.1, or PyQt-.5.3.2. What specific version are you using? Are you able to test on a different platform/machine?

Comment: I'm using PyQt-5.2.1 which comes from ubuntu repositories. Should I use more recent version ? And can I try PyQt-5.5.0 without uninstalling current version ?

Comment: Best guess would be that upgrading will fix the problem. It would probably be easier to just upgrade ubuntu if you can, as compiling pyqt is not that straightforward (you'd also need to compile the latest sip and a separate python as well).